# Convert HTTP requests to Socks5 with squid3

Tags: proxy, tor, squid, socks5, privoxy

I am new to Squid3.

My question is duplicated with [Convert HTTP requests to SOCKS5](https://superuser.com/questions/423563/convert-http-requests-to-socks5?newreg=6a70d56ecd654267b86b6afcd88c50c8).
The difference is that I want to achieve it with [Squid3](http://www.squid-cache.org/), but I can not find any configuration in Squid3's documentation.

Is there any configuration in Squid3 that can do this easily just like Polipo:

```
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

or like Privoxy:

```
forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

?

Comment: Well, from what I'm seeing in your linked answer, you would want to point your local hosts to the DeleGate instance, and have DeleGate point to your Squid.  This of course, is only for applications that can't be told that they are to use an SOCKS5 proxy natively. For those applications you would point them straight at squid. Either way, this shoudl occur upstream from Squid.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use DeleGate.

Comment: I add more detail in question content. I just want to expose port 3128 to internet, and pass all requests from 3128 to 9050. The reason I don't use Polipo or Privoxy is that Privoxy don't support access authorization and Polipo often break down on my production server.

Comment: if Squid doesn't natively support making upstream SOCKS connections, then you will need additional software to do this.  there may be some auto SOCKS client you can use depending on your platform.  Or you could use a different proxy that supports upstream connections with SOCKS, such as our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com), which does support authentication.  Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.

Comment: @Adrien My server is running on ubuntu, not windows. Thanks anyway.